# Пропал звук после установки видеокарты

Tags: аудио, nvidia, hdmi

В общем такая проблема. Установил новую видеокарту и сразу пропал звук. Средство проигрывания аудио стал HDMI в видеокарте, а надо чтобы через аукс. Сделал помоему все что было возможно, включая переустановку всех драйверов, проверку в биосе(все включено там) и диагностику неисправностей аидой. Подскажите, что можн осделать с этим?[image: такие устройтва доступны, включени отображение для невидимых и отключеных]

[image: Диагностика Аидой64]

[image: Диспетчер устройств]

Comment: Скорее всего на видеокарте есть своя звуковая карта и она не может работать совместно со встроенной. Те работать может только одна из них. В биосе есть настройка и нужно включить встроенную звуковую карту самому(при установленной видеокарте). Попробуйте изменить в BIOS опцию Auto на Enable параметра "Onbord Ac'97" или "Onbord HDMI". Или попробуйте в панели управления отключить видеокарту в звуковых устройствах.

Comment: Также вроде есть мониторы с аудиовыходом для таких видеокарт. К видеокарте они подключаются по HDMI а к монитору можно подключить наушники.